# See daily limits

Tags: support, rate-limiting, voting-limits

Is there a place where you can monitor all the limits for the current day?

I know for example on votes, it will notify you on the last 5 votes you have left over. Is there something similar for other limits?

Comment: What other limits are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where you can monitor all the limits for the current day?

The activity tab in your profile but it won't cover everything like flag.

If you want to see vote limit, you have to check the votes tab in your activity tab and count the votes you cast today.

[image]

If you want to check other things like Close Vote, Flag, etc, there is an easy way.

Open the close pop up by clicking the *close* link in a post

[image]

for flags, open the flag dialog by clicking the Flag on a post

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There's no central 'dashboard' for them. That's probably [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign); you should vote because you see good/bad content, irrespective of whether you hit a limit or not.

You can see the number of up- and downvotes today in your [user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current#user-panel-votes), in the Votes Cast section. This doesn't tell you the number of votes on questions *today* which is important for the height of the limit.

[image]

Other vote types (close, delete, etc.) are also limited; the only way to see those is the [Votes tab on your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes) and count them manually.